# Access the object Inside Anonymous Handler function

Tags: java, vert.x

I have a very basic question. I have just started with vertx Framework. There is one thing I am not able to understand like

```
vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(new Handler<NetSocket>() {
@Override
public void handle(final NetSocket socket) {

    socket.dataHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
        public void handle(Buffer buffer) {
            /* I can access the socket object inside this handler */
            socket.write("Hello");
        }
    });
}
}).listen(1234);
```

but if I write the handler function separately like this

```
Handler<Message> socketHandler = new Handler<Buffer>() {
        public void handle(Buffer buffer) {
            /* How can i access the socket object now */
            socket.write("Hello"); //this will give error as it does not recognize the socket object
        }
    };


vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(new Handler<NetSocket>() {
@Override
public void handle(final NetSocket socket) {
    socket.dataHandler(socketHandler);//now I write handler separately
}
}).listen(1234);
```

Handler can be anywhere in the same java class or other java class. Please help me me how I can write handler separately and still access the socket object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example, you're not passing `socket` to `socketHandler`, so you cannot expect `socketHandler` to know about it.

You could solve this by creating a method like `createSocketHandler(final Socket socket)` that returns a `Handler<Message>` and that replaces your `socketHandler` variable.

To learn more, and to find out why you need `socket` to be `final`, look up "anonymous inner classes"